# Calling custom objects whose names contain numbers in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I have declared custom objects in Objective-c project:

```
Student* student1 = [[Student alloc]init];
Student* student2 = [[Student alloc]init];
Student* student3 = [[Student alloc]init];
Student* student4 = [[Student alloc]init];
Student* student5 = [[Student alloc]init];
Student* student6 = [[Student alloc]init];
```

How can I call them in cycle

```
for (int i=1; i<=6; i++)
{
}   ?
```

Comment: You should be using an array for this

Comment: **You don't!** Use an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly do that. You could use an array (either C-style or an `NSArray`) and then iterate over that (using zero-based indexes or a for-in loop).

For example:

```
NSArray* students = @[ [[Student alloc] init],
                       [[Student alloc] init],
                       [[Student alloc] init],
                       [[Student alloc] init],
                       [[Student alloc] init],
                       [[Student alloc] init],
                     ];
for (int i = 0; i < students.count; i++)
{
    Student* student = students[i];
    // Do something with student
}
// Or:
for (Student* student in students)
{
    // Do something with student
}
```